# How to add programs to the open with menu?

Tags: nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add custom command in the open with dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67382/add-custom-command-in-the-open-with-dialog)

I had tried to look around an open with tab under a file properties, There are no option to add programs into that list of other applications

I just want to set **[sqlite database browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/)** as my default program for an extension **.db**

**Update**:
I found [duplicated question in 2011](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67382/add-custom-command-in-the-open-with-dialog).. there are smarter way on GUI based?

so I am looking for something like [Set Default Open Program - Ubuntu 9.04](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bds1lG7gn8) (why do ubuntu downgrade itself?)