# ubuntu 12.04 how can I gain access to arbitrary applications in Nautilus' "open with" dialog

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, default-programs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add custom command in the open with dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67382/add-custom-command-in-the-open-with-dialog)

I want to set a filetype to be opened by a specific program other than ubuntu's default. I usually

right click > properties > open with

and select the application I need. This however does not work in this case.

The application I want is not shown in the "open with" dialog and there apparently is no way I can browse to it or type in a custom command like I used to in 10.04.

I'm aware of the above work-around which will work for each individual file but not make the app generally available from the "open with" dialog.

Is this a bug that I should file or a feature that can be worked around?

Comment: Thanks, a bit eerie, though. I want to associate a "test.php" with sublime text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: right click file, open with other application, then select the application in the menu.

But if you really command you can take a look at http://www.packtpub.com/article/control-of-file-types-in-ubuntu using mime you can change the default type for any extension, granted you know the command for launching it in command line.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I may have been unclear but I have done exactly what you suggested. Can I conclude that this is a bug? Perhaps you would know where this should be filed (I know how but I don't know which project)

Comment: not sure where it would go, tempted to say nautilus, because if mime works well with other extensions then its probably not a bug.