# Invalid desktop entry file Error for AppImage (resolved)

Tags: lubuntu, minecraft

I am on Lubuntu 22.04 LTS. I right clicked at home screen and clicked create new launcher for my Lunar Client AppImage. I inputted some stuff. If I right click it and open it in FeatherPad, here is what it shows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Lunar Client
GenericName=Lunar Client
Comment=Lunar Client
Exec=/home/tejas72/Lunar Client-3.2.0.AppImage
Type=Application
Icon=/home/tejas72/LunarClientLogo.jpeg
Terminal=false
```

but now I get the error message
`Invalid desktop entry file: '/home/tejas72/Desktop/Lunar_Client.desktop'` when I double click it from home screen. what do I do? I have sudo privilege and anything. Pls say everything in detail as I might not understand some things.
EDIT: Both the appimage and the logo are in my /home/tejas72 folder

EDIT: I removed the space and it all worked, thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have a space in the filename you'll need to change the line

```
Exec=/home/tejas72/Lunar Client-3.2.0.AppImage
```

to

```
Exec="/home/tejas72/Lunar Client-3.2.0.AppImage"
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still gives me the same error, (Added the single quotation marks around it)

Comment: Did you give the appimage execute permissions? `chmod +x '/home/tejas72/Lunar Client-3.2.0.AppImage'` Also, where is your `.desktop`-file located? Does the `.desktop`-file has execute permission?

Comment: [The Exec key](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) of the freedesktop specification calls for *double quotes*

Comment: ...  you could also try replacing the space with `\s` - see for example [How to escape spaces in .desktop files Exec line](https://askubuntu.com/a/1026400/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver For me the desktop-file also works with single quotes.

Comment: @mook765 good to know - thanks

Comment: so would I do Exec="/home/tejas72/Lunar\sClient-3.2.0.AppImage"

Comment: It has permissions, and it is lokacted in /tejas72 right now
i have tried single and double quotes