# How do you select an arbitrary application to "open with"?

Tags: filemanager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add custom command in the open with dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67382/add-custom-command-in-the-open-with-dialog)

I would like to open e.g. webm files using mplayer, but it is not available in the "Open With" dialogue and (quite frustratingly) the dialogue no longer allows selection of the program to use from the file system.

Is there a conf file I can edit directly to get this done?

Comment: Hi Tomislav.... which "buntu" are you running?

Comment: I'm using 11.10 and Unity.

Comment: @izx Indeed, this is an exact duplicate.

Comment: Try Nautilus actions.

Answer (score 0):

If you'r using 11.10 i found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11357219&postcount=2) for an application called nedit.

Quoting **mc4man**

> fairly easy - nedit's .desktop is missing something to allow it to be shown in the r. click context menu
>
> ```
> Code:
> gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/nedit.desktop
> ```
>
> find the Exec= line & add a %f to end, leave a space between nedit & %f - ignore the untitled document 1 that also opens - close it without saving, do save the nedit.desktop
>
> ```
> Code:
> [Desktop Entry]
> Version=1.0
> Name=NEdit
> Exec=nedit %f
> Icon=Nedit
> Terminal=false
> Type=Application
> Categories=Motif;Utility;TextTools;
> GenericName=Text editor
> GenericName[en]=Text editor
> GenericName[nl]=Tekst verwerker
> ```
>
> Then you'll find it by right clicking on your **file > open with > other applications**
>   After that it will be shown directly in the r. click menu
>
> If you wish to set nedit as default for all text files then use the right click **> Properties > open with** instead

If, in other hand, you're using 12.04 you can do it like [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-addremove-applications-from-open-with-window.html):

> If you want to delete applications from the openwith list you have to edit the following file from command line
>
> */usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache*
>
> **If you added item by yourself**, or you want to **add new item** you need to edit the following file from command line
>
> *~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache*
>
> **default actions** you need to edit the following file from command line
>
> *~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list*

Comment: I have nor the the mimeinfo.cache nor the defaults.list: the only file I have in that folder is mimeapps.list...I would say we're probably using different versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

There will be one more option like open with other application , select that . a window will open with browse option and navigate to usr and then to bin folder and there you can select the application you want .

I am using KDE and i will post those images and i hope they will help you to understand .
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: While I am grateful for the advice, I'm using 11.10 and Unity, so I don't think these instructions would help me.

Comment: My intension behind this is to make you understand what you have to do . :D