# Open with Open Office

Tags: openoffice.org

I just installed Open Office from the deb package. By default, it is installed in /opt so I can start OO writer with:

```
/opt/openoffice4/program/soffice
```

But, I want it to automatically open .docx files.

When I right-click on a docx file and select "Open With", it doesn't let me select Open Office. How can I tell Ubuntu to always open docx files with `/opt/openoffice4/program/soffice` ?

I have Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can change defaults by following method:**

1. Open `defaults.list` by following command:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/gnome/defaults.list
   ```
2. Wher you find following line which is default for Libre-office:

   ```
   application/msword=libreoffice-writer.desktop
   ```
3. Replace with open-office desktop file:

   ```
   application/msword=openoffice-writer.desktop
   ```
4. Save file and exit.

**Note**: In file `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` you can change default applications with desktop file (for find extension or app name you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for replace).

---

**Additional Information:**

The file `openoffice-writer.desktop` should be exist in `/usr/share/applications` (Recommended to put/use provided desktop file) If not, then you can create as follows:

- `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/openoffice-writer.desktop`
- Then put following data in file

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=OpenOffice Writer
  Icon=libreoffice-writer
  Type=Application
  Exec=/opt/openoffice4/program/soffice %U
  ```
- Then save and close it.
- Give execution permission by `sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/openoffice-writer.desktop`

Now set file as default as mentioned first.

---

**Note**: Here `openoffice-writer.desktop` is only suggested example name. **Use provided desktop file if exist.**

Comment: N.B. .desktop files can also have mimetypes - in this case something like `MimeType=application/msword;application/vnd.ms-word;application/x-doc;application/x-hwp;application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12;application/vnd.ms-works;` could cover doc files. Adding `Categories=Office;WordProcessor;` may also mean it is sorted correctly in application menus/dash/whatever. If using `gedit`, `gksudo` or similar should probably be used as well - chmod/chown could also be used to give the file read-write permissions to non-root users.

Comment: @Wilf Yes welcome to Improve this answer by adding proper `MimeType`

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed information! I followed your instructions and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there was not been created .desktop files, i don't know where they are in ubuntu 12.04, but there are a lot of application to create these files. For instance https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/create-launcher/ but more standard and longer solution is explained in [Add custom command in the open with dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67382/add-custom-command-in-the-open-with-dialog) , I havent tested these solutions on Ubuntu 12.04 but it should work.