# Add custom command in the open with dialog? - Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Tags: nautilus, customization, matlab, default-programs

I am trying to associate .fig files (generated by MATLAB) so that I can open them easily by double clicking them. An easy way of doing that in Ubuntu versions before 16.04 is to use the custom command option after installing Ubuntu-Tweak tool (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544342/open-matlab-figure-in-ubuntu , [Add custom command in the open with dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67382/add-custom-command-in-the-open-with-dialog)).

Ubuntu 16.04, however, does not have the Ubuntu-Tweak tool. I tried solutions which do not need the tweak tool, but those approaches do not work (like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72535/creating-desktop-files-to-use-on-the-open-with-other-application-tab)).
How can I set a custom command for files with a particular extension in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: ubuntu-tweak should be available for 16.04 as well, I think...

Comment: See the answer here specific to 16.04 (and the other answers to that question as well) to find out how to install Ubuntu Tweak: http://askubuntu.com/a/781586/367990

Answer (score 0):

I don't like unofficial repos, so I did it manually, in my case with truecrypt. I think you can use

The 1st step is: Is there any related MIME type exists? I tried to find the .tc extension or the truecrypt text:

```
grep -i -e "\.tc" /usr/share/mime/packages/*
grep -i -e "truec" /usr/share/mime/packages/*
```

I didn't find anything, so I created it into /usr/share/mime/packages/truecrypt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
    <mime-type type="application/x-truecrypt">
        <comment>TrueCrypt encrypted file container</comment>
        <icon name="truecrypt"/>
        <glob-deleteall/>
        <glob pattern="*.tc"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

I found 3 matches for the .fig extension (under the image/x-fig MIME type by freedesktop, and under application/x-cabri in kde.xml) so I think you don't need to create this, but someone may find it useful.

In my case the truecrypt.desktop file did not contain any MIME type info, so I added this mime type to the end of the file: /usr/share/applications/truecrypt.desktop

```
MimeType=application/x-truecrypt
```

My new MIME type was not associated with any program, so I added this line to the end of the default file, which is in /usr/share/applications/defaults.list

```
application/x-truecrypt=truecrpyt.desktop
```

If your MIME type existed, I think you need to change this association instead of creating one more.

At last update the databases:

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
sudo update-desktop-database
```