# How to run sh file from terminal?

Tags: command-line

I installed `Viber` on Ubuntu:

```
/home/nazar/Software/Viber/Viber.sh
```

I can run it from terminal specifying this path. I want to achieve some short command as:

```
viber
```

For lunching application.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: This post is contain everything you need

http://askubuntu.com/questions/37401/how-do-i-add-a-launcher-for-sh-applications

Comment: If you want to run `Viber.sh ` just by typing in terminal, then add `/home/nazar/Software/Viber/` to your `$PATH` variable. [This post](http://askubuntu.com/q/60218/295286) explains how to do it. If you find this useful, don't forget to upvote the helpful answers there

Comment: Or put the script in a more standard location such as ~/bin/viper.sh (does not require root access) or /usr/local/bin/viper.sh (requires root access).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an `alias` of the full command by running the following in the terminal:

```
alias viber=/home/nazar/Software/Viber/Viber.sh
```

Now you can run the script by just typing `viber`.

Note that this will be working for the current session of the shell only. To make it permanent save it in `~/.bash_aliases` (or `~/.bashrc`):

```
$ echo 'alias viber=/home/nazar/Software/Viber/Viber.sh' >> ~/.bash_aliases
$ source ~/.bash_aliases
```

The first command will save the alias permanently in `~/.bash_aliases`, the preferred file to save aliases. It will create the file if not exists already. The second command will make the alias working from the current shell session.

An alternate method is to create a symbolic link of the executable script in the `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin` directory(given they are in your `PATH` environment variable).

```
sudo ln -s /home/nazar/Software/Viber/Viber.sh /usr/local/bin/viber
```

As the directory is owned by user `root` and group `root`, make sure `/usr/local/bin/viber` has execute permission for all others (`a+x`).

By using any one of the above methods, you can run the script by simply typing `viber`.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to create a script with that name somewhere on your `PATH`. This is a little overkill for this specific case; overall heemayl's answer is probably better for you.

First, make the directory `~/bin` if you don't have it already:

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

Now edit the file `~/bin/viber` and save it with the following contents (change the first line if you use a different default shell):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

/home/nazar/Software/Viber/Viber.sh
```

Finally make the script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/viber
```

And now you should be able to run the program with just `viber`.