# How to create an app launcher/app shortcut in Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome, launcher

Is there a good tutorial on how to make a good app launcher in Gnome 3?

I copied one in `/usr/share/applications`, changed the name and paths accordingly, but it didn't show up in my list of apps then.

Thank you

Comment: Did you logout and back in? I remember I had to do that when I manually added an entry in Ubuntu

Comment: Hi. Yes, I tried logging in and out, but it didn't do anything. I thought it would be a safe bet copying an existing .desktop file, but seems not :)

Comment: See this comment from James: https://askubuntu.com/questions/37401/how-do-i-add-a-launcher-for-sh-applications?rq=1#comment41734_37717

Comment: For a simple GUI solution you may try **Alacarte** aka **Main Menu**.

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in dash/dock in GNOME's overview screen? You can also install `Dash to Dock` GNOME extension. Tell me more about your needs.

Comment: There's nothing wrong except the created shortcut doesn't show up.

Comment: What shortcut? Where is it located? Did you drag it into the dock? Start comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Answer (score 4):

How it definitely does work is:

1. copy an existing `/usr/share/applications/application.desktop` file
2. edit the names of the app, and app path and icon path accordingly.
3. save it as `xyz.desktop`

You'll have a working launcher.